# android emulator won't start, couldn't find the apk file

Tags: java, android, keystore

Can anybody help my problem, when I start a new project it says I got java IOException Error and says something like keystore was tampered or password incorrect. I delete the error by right clicking  it and the error was gone, but when I want to start the emulator, the emulator won't start and gives me error : couldn't find the [project's] apk.
I know this question has been asked before but i just couldn't help myself to get the problem and ask it again anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why dont you delete the emulator and create a new one and try again??